# What is the fastest connection method to debug a windows 10/7 kernel using windbg?

Tags: debugging, window, kernel, windbg, windows-kernel

There seems to be many methods for debugging a windows 10/7, including USB or network or COM

But which of them is the fastest? I have only used COM and it seems to be really slow compared to debugging a local usermode application, was wondering what is the fastest method? is there any method that makes debugging kernel as fast as user-mode apps or close?

by fast I mean for example the amount of time for the single steps to take or amount of time for windbg to execute commands, because right now even the simplest commands sometimes take too long

Also what is the fastest method for windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two factors coming in: baud rate (data transfer rate) and response time (ping time). It depends much on what task you perform.

Creating a full memory kernel crash dump will likely transfer a lot of data, so a higher bandwidth is helpful.

On the other hand side, sending small WinDbg commands like `k` or `|` have just small amount of data, but you typically send it and wait for the answer. In that case, the response time has more effect.

For baud rates:

- COM port is a serial port and can be configured from 75 baud up to 2 MBit/s.
- USB depends on the version and has 12 MBit/s up to 10 GBit/s on USB 3.2 generation 2.
- Firewire is available from 100 MBit/s to 3200 MBit/s.
- Network, well has typical values from 10 MBit/s to 10 GBit/s. But of course if you debug over the Internet, it won't be faster than your DSL or cable modem.

For ping time:

- USB has a response time of less than 1 ms, but that may depend on how many devices you connect.
- A local full duplex network also has a response time of less than 1 ms.
- Debugging over the Internet is pretty slow with 20 ms up to 300 ms.

From an availability and cost standpoint, I would start with a 1 GBit/s network connection. If you don't have that yet, you can buy a cheap Gigabit USB adapter for 12 € or so.

> which of them is the fastest?

As I hopefully explained well enough, that's a question which can only be answered when we know the exact situation

> I have only used COM and it seems to be really slow

Yes. It is.

> right now even the simplest commands sometimes take too long

From a performance view, that's not something we can work with. If you define performance requirements, we'd need to know a) how fast is it now and b) how fast is acceptable for you.

> What is the fastest method for windows 7?

I don't think the operating system matters much here.

Comment: As a side note, Net debugging (KDNET) is only available starting with Windows 8 for the target machine.

Comment: @Neitsa: thanks for the information. I wasn't aware of that

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thanks for the answer!  I tried KDNet but the time taken for executing windbg commands didn't seem much different from COM, so will switching to USB make any difference? or any other suggestion? I just want windbg to execute command as fast as possible. also in your answer you included ping time and baud rate, but what about time that takes for executing commands?

Comment: also  my network connection with guest is good, 1ms and +1GB/s

Comment: @Notoriouss it's still not clear to me how slow it is. How long does it take to run the `k` command for example? Do it 10 times. Is it different depending on the commands? How about `r` or `.echo X`?

Comment: @ThomasWeller it depends on the command, some commands like k take 0.5 sec to finish or dt_structure address take less than 2-3 seconds, but commands like !drvobj !devobj !devstack which I mostly work with take for ever. right now the command drvobj address 2 takes 90 seconds to finish!! but the dt_driver_object on the same address takes 1 second instead of 90! is this normal? should I open another thread for this problem?

Comment: @Notoriouss: at least this reaches a level now at which I can't help any more. I'm not a driver developer, so I'm not familiar with what an average time should be. There are people monitoring the WinDbg tag, so asking a new question for this topic seems ok.

Comment: @Notoriouss these commands have been really slow since quite a good deal of time now. I'm not sure if it's a windbg problem or from the kernel itself (not exporting some global variables needed for those commands), but any command involving a device object is slow. It's not just you.

Comment: @Neitsa so switching to USB or other connection methods wouldn't help much correct? because it is really a pain to wait 90 seconds for each of these commands

Comment: @Notoriouss Sadly, no. AFAIK, there is no way to alleviate this problem...

Answer (score 1):

1394 is the fastest one I used on Win 7. USB debugging is also possible, but you need to make sure the usb port (usually the onboard one) supports debugging - not all ports support this. On Win 10, KDNet probably is the fastest so far.

However, if you are debugging a virtual machine with VMWare or VirtualBox, VirtualKD is even faster than any above physical connections since it just copies data between the guest and the host. Btw, its implementation is very interesting.

All of the above is way more faster than COM. You won't feel much differences unless you are generating a full memory dump, and even that's the case none of them will seriously cause you real pain.